# Different font for math character in TexStudio

Tags: fontsize, texstudio

While changing some syntax highlighting settings, something accidentally happened in the TexStudio editor that made the macros a different font. How to change back? It looks like this now.

[image]

Comment: If you have change a file you can go on the [github of texstudio](https://github.com/texstudio-org/texstudio) get the old file and replace. The `tex.qnfa` file is in `utilities/qxs`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It seems like you've changed the font family for `keyword` in the settings. You can restore the default there:

[image]

Comment: Thanks. More accurately, it was the 'math-keyword', not 'keyword'. It sucks that if you use the mouse scroller when hovering over the font box, it changes abruptly.

Comment: To clarify I was meaning to say that the reason my accidental change happened was because of the hovering scroller.